# Profile Picture for Sandbox User

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, sandbox, site-design

The sandbox is now owned by a dummy account, [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/31362/sandbox). At the moment it has a default profile picture.

Can we create/find a profile picture for it that illustrates that:

- the user is a dummy account
- the user's sole purpose is to run the sandbox

I think we may want something like the [Community](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) user's profile.

(And, while we're at it, maybe a description that explains what the user does?)

Comment: I made a few changes (see the comment below on @Rusher's answer).

Comment: Why not simply [the same image](https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/a007be5a61f6aa8f3e85ae2fc18dd66e?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG) as the Community user?

Comment: @Calvin'sHobbies It might get confused though. It's not a bad idea.

Answer (score 3):

I took the liberty of writing out a profile for our beloved Sandbox. I kept it simple. He doesn't actually "run" the Sandbox. He just exists so that nobody else gets all of the notifications.

Add our website to his bio:

> website codegolf.stackexchange.com

Set his profile text as follows:

> Hi, I'm not really a person.
>
> I exist to own the [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2140/18487), so that no single member of the community has to endure the constant updates being made to it.

He *owns* the Sandbox, but he is not a Sandbox. Fill the blank below with your own suggestion in the comments. Upvote your favorite suggestions!

```
Community : Stack Exchange :: _______ : Sandbox
```

Someone from PPCG should create original art for Sandbox. Heck, you could even make a pop contest out of it if you took the time to write a solid-enough spec.

Comment: I went ahead and applied these changes, and also threw together a really terrible avatar image as a placeholder until a better one is made / found. (Fun fact: The Sandbox user currently has 58 notifications.)

Comment: For a name, I keep coming back to the idea of [the rakes](http://www.trumbullrecreation.com/i//Pool_PondSandComb.jpg) people use to keep golf bunkers tidy. Seems fitting, but I don't know how to work that in.

Comment: @Doorknob Maybe the website should be the address of the sandbox? (The avatar really isn't that bad)